# Решение СЛАУ методом Зейделя

Tags: c++

Остался последний фрагмент на стадии итерации:

```
double A [2][3] = {{ -5, -1, -4}, { -4, 4, -5}}; //матрица с коэффициентами при двух неизвестных
double epsilon = 0.001;
double x[3], y[3]; // массивы для значений x и y
x[0] = 0, y[0] = 0;
i = 0;

do
{
    x[i + 1] = (A[i][i + 2] - A[i][i + 1] * y[i]) / A[i][i];
    y[i + 1] = (A[i + 1][i + 2] - A[i + 1][i] * x[i + 1]) / A[i + 1][i +
               1];
    cout << "Решение на " << i << "-ой " << "итерации - "
         << "x = " << round(x[i + 1] * 10000) / 10000 << ", y =" << round(
             y[i + 1] * 10000) / 10000 << "\n";
    i++;
}
while (abs(x[i + 1]) < epsilon && i < 3);
```

Значения на первой итерации высчитывает верно x[1] = -0.8, y[1] = -2.05, а последующие итерации выводит с ошибкой. Я так понимаю, что надо правильно присвоить предыдущие значение x и y следующим.

Comment: Значения на первой итерации высчитывает верно x[1] = -0.8, y[1] = -2.05, а последующие итерации выводит с ошибкой. Я так понимаю, что надо правильно присвоить предыдущие значение x и y следующим.

Comment: Все важные моменты по вопросу вносите в тело самого вопроса, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Понимаете, у вас написана такая ерунда, что ее **исправлять** - все равно что напильником из бруска металла вытачивать самолет. Ее надо **переписывать**. Уже при `i==1` вы обращаетесь к элементу, например, `A[2][3]` - ну, и где он у вас? А при `i==2` все и того хуже... И все это никак не соответствует заявленному методу.

Comment: @Harry, большое спасибо, я разобрался с Вашей помощью. Я совсем ещё новичок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то если у вас не для общего случая, а для двух переменных, то достаточно так:

```
double A [2][3] = {{ -5, -1, -4}, { -4, 4, -5}}; //матрица с коэффициентами при двух неизвестных
const double epsilon = 0.0001;

int main()
{
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    double norm = 2*epsilon;
    for(int i = 1;norm >= epsilon;++i)
    {
        double x1 = (A[0][2]-A[0][1]*y)/A[0][0];
        double y1 = (A[1][2]-A[1][0]*x1)/A[1][1];
        norm = abs(x1-x)+abs(y1-y);
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        cout << "Iteration " << i << ": "
            << "x = " << setw(8) << x
            << "  y = " << setw(8) << y << endl;
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
Iteration 1: x =      0.8  y =    -0.45
Iteration 2: x =     0.89  y =    -0.36
Iteration 3: x =    0.872  y =   -0.378
Iteration 4: x =   0.8756  y =  -0.3744
Iteration 5: x =  0.87488  y = -0.37512
Iteration 6: x = 0.875024  y = -0.374976
Iteration 7: x = 0.874995  y = -0.375005
```

Comment: @alexolut 32, ок, извините, не так давно тут, раньше спрашивал на киберфоруме все

Comment: вы мой спаситель...)) теперь я  понял наконец-то в чем ошибка))

Comment: Ну, тогда пометьте ответ как принятый :)